# Formatting references in elsarticle for Food Hydrocolloids

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

I am trying to format the references of my article following the author guidelines from Food Hydrocolloids (attached here the format needed):

> All citations in the text should refer to:
>
> 1. Single author: the author's name (without initials, unless there is ambiguity) and the year of publication (Smith, 2003).
> 2. Two authors: both authors' names and the year of publication (Smith & Jones, 2004).
> 3. Three, four or five authors: all authors names and year of publication (Smith, Jones, & Brown, 2005). For all subsequent citations of this work use et al. (Smith et al., 2005).
> 4. Six or more authors: first author's name followed by et al. and the year of publication (Black et al., 2007).

However, I am using the `elsarticle` class, and the closes thing I can get is by using the command

```
\bibliographystyle{model5-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}
```

but then only the first author (+ "et al.") appears from the beginning of the document, instead of all the authors up to 5. There might be a relatively straightforward way of doing it, as I imagine previous author have submitted LaTX manuscripts to *Food Hydrocolloids*, but I cannot find the answer to this anywhere. As far as I can tell it is an APA citation style, but I cannot achieve it within the `elsarticle` class.

I am happy to provide any more information if needed.

Comment: Since `elsarticle` is not compatible with `biblatex` and journal submissions with `biblatex` are still rare I have removed that tag and instead added the more generic bibliographies tag. Have you tried to contact the editor for advice? Given the subject matter of the journal I wouldn't be so sure that there have been many previous LaTeX submissions.

Comment: The standard BibTeX way to produce APA citations is the `apacite` package, but I'm not sure if it is (fully) compatible with `elsarticle`.

Comment: Thanks for changing the tag.

Indeed I had tried with 'apacite', but it did not work neither. Apparently an easy solution I just find is to use `\citep*{}` instead of `\citep{}` I was using, which now prints all the names of the authors. The downside is that I have to check manually whether is the first in-text citation, or subsequents ones, and then use `\citep*{}` or `\citep{}` accordingly.

Thank you for the answers!